# Setting up redirection for www website to non www

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

We have our website hosted up on AWS EC2 instance behind the Application Load Balancer. Our Route 53 is targetting the Application Load Balancer.

Assuming we have a domain name - `company.com`

we have SSL registered for this domain `*.company.com`. We have this certificate enabled on the Application load balancer at 443 port.

We want our website hosted at subdomain - `sub.company.com`

Current Scenario:

When we access the website with `http://www.sub.company.com` or `http://sub.company.com` or `https://sub.company.com`.
With the rewrite rule for the first two, we are able to redirect to the third endpoint mentioned.

Problem arises in this particular case where we are trying to access the website with `https://www.sub.example.com`, It gives us a Non Secure Warning. How can we redirect this to `https://sub.example.com` ?

Things I have tried:

1. I have tried adding Rewrite rules on the webserver of EC2 Instance.
2. Added routing rules at Application Load balancer to redirect it at `https://sub.example.com`

Both of these solutions are not able to resolve the problem, It's maybe because SSL validation is happening at the first step of connection establishment before it reaches to load balancer layer.

How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you request a wildcard certificate, the asterisk (*) must be in the leftmost position of the domain name and can protect only one subdomain level.
For example, *.example.com can protect login.example.com and test.example.com, but it cannot protect test.login.example.com. then you have to request a separate certificate for *.login.example.com